# Suddenly cocoapods error and gradle task failed error in Android studio for specific Flutter project with external packages

Tags: ios, flutter, android-studio

Android emulators and iOS simulators in my Android studio were working perfect for all Flutter projects until I created a specific one with 2 external packages (english_words: ^4.0.0 audioplayers: ^5.0.0). This new project raises cocoapods error when I run on iOS simulator and 'Gradle task assembleDebug failed' error. Attaching the error logs for your reference. This never happened for my previous projects **I am working on Macbook Pro (M2 Pro) and Android Studio Giraffe.**

iOS simulator error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
        WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
        Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

        export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
        
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `unicode_normalize'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:105:in `markdown_podfile'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:30:in `report'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `unicode_normalize'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:205:in `podfile'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:160:in `verify_podfile_exists!'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:46:in `run'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
        from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
```

**UPDATE (05/08/2023):**
I had already install cocoapods using homebrew. I used the following commands and iOS simulator is working. Android emulators are still in the same state.

```
brew uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.4 [not required if next command does not ask to install this]
sudo gem install cocoapods -V  
open ~/.zshrc
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 [add this line]
source ~/.zshrc
```

Type locale to check if everything is of the below form:

```
LANG=""
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Good to go!

Android emulator error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.ExperimentalPathApi found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathRelativizer found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathReadWriteKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathUtilsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.jdk8.JvmRepeatableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$2 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$3 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$4 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)

     Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```